# Make an image as a background of a resizable component

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a simple layout composed by two columns: the left one should have width 30% of the container, and the right one should take up the remaining space.
Everything should work on desktop, tablet and mobile so on every devices.

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) but the image should not be the window page background but only the right panel.

So:

- the image should fill entire `right` div, no white space
- scales image as needed
- retains image proportions (aspect ratio)
- image is centered inside the `right` div
- does not cause scrollbars
- as cross-browser compatible as possible.

```css
.page {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid steelblue;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="left">This is the left panel with some content</div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://siameseofday.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Ragdoll-Cat-min-scaled.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

There's something wrong in my code because the left panel is not 30% of the container and then I don't know how to do the rest. The only examples I read are about the entire window, not only a div container.
Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's easy to do with grid and flex. Refer this [video](https://youtu.be/sD0FSfqmGaM?t=330) on how to maintain a left and right space.

In regards to the right image should be responsive and maintain ratio with cross-browser. I suggest the below.

```css
.page {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid steelblue;
}

.right {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  background: url(https://siameseofday.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Ragdoll-Cat-min-scaled.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="left">This is the left panel with some content</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```